# How to create symlink in rpm to files provided by external rpms?

Tags: java, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to package two symlinks to corresponding jars provided by external `dep1.rpm` and `dep2.rpm`. These are declared as dependencies in `my-app-extra.spec`:

```
Requires: dep1
Requires: dep2
```

I have my `%install` symlinking their jars (`%dep1jar`, `%dep2jar`):

```
%install
%{__install} -d -m 0755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_javadir}
%{__install} -d -m 0755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_javadir}/%{my_app}
pushd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_javadir}/%{my_app}
    for jar in %dep1jar %dep2jar
    do
        ln -sf ../"${jar}" "${jar}"
    done
popd
```

but the rpmbuild fails with:

```
ERROR: link target doesn't exist (neither in build root nor in installed system):
  /usr/share/java/my-app/dep1.jar -> /usr/share/java/dep1.jar
Add the package providing the target to neededforbuild and Requires
// same error for dep2.jar
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.31253 (%install)
```

Is there any way to circumvent this rpmbuild check?

---

#### Background

I have a java application that (optionally) requires two external libraries to provide extended functionality. To install these libraries, I have created `dep1.rpm` and `dep2.rpm` that store the jars under `%_datadir/java` and an additional `my-app-extra` rpm that should symlink those under `%_datadir/java/my-app` (following some apparently established java-packaging conventions under linux).

But I'm failing to find how to force rpmbuild to build this rpm without declaring the external libraries as `BuidRequires` and having them installed first.

#### What I want

This is in summary what I'm after (simplified, as the complete solution involves versioning):

```
/usr/share/java/dep1.jar (from dep1.rpm)
/usr/share/java/dep2.jar (from dep2.rpm)

/usr/share/java/my-app/dep1.jar -> ../dep1.jar (from my-app-extended.rpm)
/usr/share/java/my-app/dep2.jar -> ../dep2.jar (from my-app-extended.rpm)
```

Note: I'm now exploring the possibilities of rpm subpackages, but I somehow expect this to be possible without subpackaging.

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work 'touching' the targets and excluding them from the files. In `my-app-extra.spec`:

```bash
%install
%{__install} -d -m 0755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_javadir}
%{__install} -d -m 0755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_javadir}/%{my_app}
pushd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_javadir}/%{my_app}
    for jar in %{dep1jar} %{dep2jar}
    do
        # touch! rpmbuild aborts the build if symlink targets missing!
        touch ../"${jar}"
        ln -sf ../"${jar}" "${jar}"
    done
popd

# more stuff ...

%files
# ...
# Exclude dummy (touched) files!
%exclude %{_javadir}/%{dep1jar}
%exclude %{_javadir}/%{dep2jar}
%{_javadir}/%{my_app}/%{dep1jar}
%{_javadir}/%{my_app}/%{dep2jar}
```

Comment: I think this is the best you're going to be able to do. You said they are optional, but you `Require` them, so they won't be optional. The only other fix I can think of is to do the symlinks in your `%post` but I don't like that because then they're not in the RPMDB as your files.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Thanks for confirming my feelings and for the heads up: the libraries are in fact optional but I see how I haven't expressed myself clearly enough. Say I have a `my-app.rpm`, and now I'm creating a `my-app-extra.rpm`. This extra rpm is wha is optional, but it has a hard dependency on `dep1.rpm` and `dep2.rpm`. I'll try to make that clear.